# Pointers required for Python Rest API Automation using pytest framework validation of API Output against the DB Queries

Tags: database, rest, validation, automation, pytest

Pointers required for Python Rest API Automation using pytest framework validating of API Output against the DB Queries

expecting for sample framework which I can refer